# no moduel named apt_pkg

Tags: python-3.x, bash, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run the sudo apt-get update command on my bash shell but I am getting this error. I tried reinstall python3-apt as some of the answers on this site suggested but it isnt working for me. Can anyone guide me how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Did you do anything that prompted `apt` to stop working, or did you receive this error after first installing WSL?

Comment: No I didnt do anything. I remember using it before my last assignment during last month and I didnt do anything afterwards. I previously had python2.7 and 3.7. Before last assignment I installed pyhthon 3.8 but this command did work after that I guess. I also uninstalled python3.7

Comment: Was the `python3.7` interpreter the system Python? You should **never** uninstall the Python interpreter that ships with your distribution. By uninstalling it, you also uninstalled all of the Python packages that your operating system depends on.

Comment: I am not sure. What should I do now?

Comment: the link you gave is for ubuntu but I am using windows 10

Comment: I deleted that comment moments after posting since it depended on `apt` working, but you should note that WSL _is_ Ubuntu, unless you opted for a different distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210903/discussion-between-osama-younus-and-brian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked by making python3 point to pyhton 3.6.8